# How to catch PostTooLargeException in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, post, error-handling

To reproduce the error, simply upload a file(s) to any POST routes in Laravel that exceeds the `post_max_size` in your `php.ini` configuration.

My goal is to simply catch the error so I can inform the user that the file(s) he uploaded is too large. Say:

```
public function postUploadAvatar(Request $request)
  try {
    // Do something with $request->get('avatar')
    // Maybe validate file, store, whatever.
  } catch (PostTooLargeException $e) {
    return 'File too large!';
  }
}
```

The above code is in standard Laravel 5 (PSR-7). The problem with it is that the function can't execute once an error occurs on the injected request. Thereby can't catch it inside the function. So how to catch it then?

Answer (score 11):

Laravel uses its `ValidatePostSize` middleware to check the `post_max_size` of the request and then throws the `PostTooLargeException` if the `CONTENT_LENGTH` of the request is too big. This means that the exception is thrown way before it even gets to your controller.

What you can do is use the `render()` method in your `App\Exceptions\Handler` e.g.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof PostTooLargeException) {
        return response('File too large!', 422);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Please note that you have to return a response from this method, you can't just return a string like you can from a controller method.

The above response is to replicate the `return 'File too large!';` you have in the example in your question, you can obviously change this to be something else.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This catches the error, allows me to handle it in some way. But along with returning a response, PHP also echoes the message"Warning: POST Content-Length of 18156282 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0". Now how may I deal with that?

Comment: @doncadavona What version or PHP are you using, what version of Laravel are you using, and what have you got your app environment set to?

Comment: I have PHP 7.0.5, Laravel 5.4. It's a Homestead environment. Set to local environment. Debug is enabled. But even if I disable debug, the warning still occurs.

Comment: @doncadavona That is weird as (unless I'm mistaken) Laravel should set `display_errors` to 'off' unless your in testing. Have you explicitly set `display_errors` to 'on' anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

You can also redirect to a Laravel view of your choice if you wish to add a more content richer response to the user.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException)
        return response()->view('errors.post-too-large');

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

**ALSO NOTE:**
For the exception to be caught you should make sure you provide the proper path to the  `PostTooLargeException` by either importing the class using the `use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException;` import statement or just writing the full path like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is rendered before the Session starts so you cannot redirect back with an error message.

You can create a new blade file and redirect there like this:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException) {
        return $this->showCustomErrorPage();
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}

protected function showCustomErrorPage()
{
    return view('errors.errors_page');
    //you can also return a response like: "return response('File too large!', 422);"

}
```

To show a static message using sessions:

1.You have to move the `ValidatePostSize` class from the `middleware` array into the `middlewareGroups` array, directly after the `StartSession`.

```
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
```

2. After that in `Handler.php` you can do:

   ```
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException) {
        return $this->showCustomErrorPage();
    }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    protected function showCustomErrorPage()
    {
        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::back()->withErrors(['max_upload' => 'The Message']);
    }
   ```
3. Show the message on your controller like this:

   ```
    @error('max_upload')
    <div class="alert" id="create-news-alert-image">{{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the render() method in your App\Exceptions\Handler:

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof PostTooLargeException) {
        return redirect()->route('errors.413');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

implement a `413` route that redirects back with error message or session flash message:

```php
Route::get('413', function (Request $request) {

    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => __('validation.post_too_large')], 413);
    }

    $request->session()->flash('error', __('validation.post_too_large'));

    return redirect()->back();
})->name('errors.413');
```

since I'm using toastr to display an error message I pass a flash message to the session, but you can also `redirect()->back()->withErrors([...])`;