# PostTooLargeException in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the post too large exception when I try to upload files which are more than 2 MB in size and I've already tried everything like increasing the post_max_size and max_upload_size in php.ini file but I am still getting the same error. When I comment the handler function in validatepostsize.php file it shows token mismatch error:

[image]

Comment: Did you restart the web server and/or php after changing the setting?

Comment: Yes i tried restarting both apache and laravel loacal development server but still getting the error

Comment: Did you verify that your changes are in effect? Try doing a `phpinfo()` and search for `post_max_size`.

Comment: Allthough you're not getting a 413, don't forget to check the max request size in the webserver's config (apache: LimitRequestBody / nginx: client_max_body_size). On apache it's defaulted to 0 but nginx does have a restricted value set on default.

Comment: I changed post_max_size in php.ini file and it shows in phpinfo() that changes that I made are in effect but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 33):

I think you can check the following parameters in your `php.ini` file like:

```
upload_max_filesize = 40m
post_max_size = 50m
```

After restart your server like (*apache*)

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Keep in mind that if you change the `php.ini` on your machine to make your code work, you will also have to do it in the production environment. If possible, a better approach would be to reduce post size for example by `compression` (if you use images).

Comment: On Windows, I've set: `post_max_size = 2G`, `upload_max_filesize = 1G` and `memory_limit = 3G` to `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\bin\php.ini`
and `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.1.6\php.ini`, then, I restarted Wamp but it still doesn't work. I still get this error: `Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException`.

Answer (score 13):

First, check your PHP version.

```
php -v
```

The command below will print the path to the php.ini file that your server is using.

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Next.

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

The values of **post_max_size**, **upload_max_filesize** and **memory_limit** by default have the value of **8M**, **2M**, and **128M** respectively.

Search for those variables and change their values, whilst ensuring that the sizes follow the same ratio as the default values.

See example below:

```
post_max_size = 2G
upload_max_filesize = 1G
memory_limit = 3G
```

For "heavy-loaded sites", it is useful to have FPM installed and running.

```
sudo apt install php7.4-fpm -y
sudo service php7.4-fpm start
```

Finally, restart your web server.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Whats is the path to the php.ini file that my server is using on Windows 11 and not Linux?

Comment: @Alex01 it would differ based on the development platform you are using, such as WAMP/XAMPP/Laragon, etc...

Comment: For me it's Wamp

Answer (score 11):

One of the issues is that the Laravel `PHP artisan serve` local development server uses the php.ini under PHP/CLI instead of under PHP/apache2

So if you are having this issue while developing with `PHP artisan serve`, go and fetch the **php.ini** that's under the `/etc/php[version]/cli` folder.

Answer (score 3):

Its not the best solution just to change parameters in php.ini and then restart apache:

```
upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 128m

//or whatever value you think is right
```

Restart apache like this:
`sudo service apache2 restart`

The best way as for me is to catch `PostTooLargeException` using `Error Handling` of laravel: [Error Handling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors)

For a detailed answer how to catch `PostTooLargeException` using `Error Handling` you can see my answer in this thread: [thread with full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42883154/how-to-catch-posttoolargeexception-in-laravel/65106172#65106172).

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am looking for the same answer for the same issue.
I have found out that the issue can be resolve with an edit of  `.htaccess` file.

Add the below code in the file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
```

**This above two line will resolve the issue but if you are adding this much size then the line below give will save you from future issue. of like execution time expire and 
    all.**

```
php_value max_input_time 120
php_value max_execution_time 120
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more accurate validation, I recommend setting the values in bytes, because 50 MB is 52428800B, which actually 52 MB, not 5000000B.

`.htaccess` example:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50000000B // 50M
php_value post_max_size 50000000B // 50M
```