# Upload file with laravel5.4 file size

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have a form with a file upload, and on that file upload I have a validation that makes sure it's an image or document and also makes sure the size can't be any larger than **2M** :

```
'insurence_document' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,pdf,doc,docx:|max:2048',
```

But I don't understand, the validation rules I have set should stop it from even getting it's a **.zip!** It's not even the correct mime type. But if I upload a smaller **.zip**, it validates fine. So the issue seems to be with larger files.

I error like Warning:

> POST Content-Length of 24479807 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608
>   bytes in Unknown on line 0

Its not aboutthe above error, it's about laravel validation not work with large upload files. I want file size maintain like 2MB only.

I want it done by laravel validation only

Comment: Did you add `{{ csrf_field() }}` to your form?

Comment: You've written `docx:`, I'm guessing this breaks the validation.

Comment: yes I add. it's not about csrf_field() , it's about if file too large when i upload I can't get validation errors

Comment: no problem with That. But if I upload a smaller .zip,  validations fine

Comment: Yes! But the error `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:` is about CSRF only. That's why I asked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719495/php-warning-post-content-length-of-8978294-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-b

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8978294 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719495/php-warning-post-content-length-of-8978294-bytes-exceeds-the-limit-of-8388608-b)

Comment: it's not about the size 2MB , it's about laravel validation won't work if i upload larger files. if i upload smaller files validations work.  @LinusJuhlin

Answer (score 0):

**8388608 bytes is 8M**, Default file upload size is **2MB**

Open the **php.ini** file. Find these lines in the *php.ini* file and replace it following numbers: `upload_max_filesize = 64M` Save the changes and try uploading the file again.

You can find the path in your *xampp/php/php.ini*(Windows User) file And must restart your server

Comment: it's not about the size 2MB , it's about laravel validation won't work if i upload larger files. if i upload smaller files validations work.

Comment: @venky Have you tried my answer? please try and let me know

Comment: I  want to work without change upload_max_filesize for laravel validation , okay if I change after that i upload more than 64MB file means same error I got right.

Comment: @venky This won't work. Before any file comes to laravel (and his validation) it's already being rejected by php.ini configuration. This is how php works.
P.S. you probably would like to increase max_post_size property in php.ini as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom Laravel validation rule for this, to figure out why this passing the Zip file and the 2mb filesize. There you would be able to handle manually the validation and see why passes the rules you want to set. If you figure it out, I'm sure you'll be able to find out why this happens.

Comment: it's not about only zip file, I tried with different formats , if it's large size file i get error page, it's not validate like laravel validation msg it's more than 2MB file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `upload_max_filesize = -1` in you **php.ini** file

Answer (score 0):

If you exceed the php limit then the server will refuse the upload before it reaches your validator. This way it will not produce the validation message but php will throw an error.
So even that the file type is different from `mime` you set up on `rule`, you will not get the message of that `rule` because it does not reach it.

Another case is if you set `required` on `rule` and the file exceed the php limit than you will receive the message from validaiton: `The field is required`. This happens for the same reason mentioned before, since the file does not reaches the validator, the validator will look at the input as an empty field and will throw the `required` message.

Solution is to change `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in your php.ini.

Happy coding!

Edit:: If you want to catch the error generated from php when you exceed the limit of `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size` you can see my answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42883154/how-to-catch-posttoolargeexception-in-laravel/65106172#65106172).